# Why 'de' was used instead of 'des' in the sentences below

Tags: grammaire, articles, accord, pluriel, noms

I come across some sentences in French that make me confused like why are the first options used instead of the second ones?

> les données de comportements des clients

vs

> les données des comportements des clients

> les profils de clients

vs

> les profils des clients

the examples article link:

https://kobia.fr/quest-ce-que-l-analyse-predictive/

to find the whole paragraph of the examples you can use ctrl+f

Comment: Welcome to FL.  Please visit [the Help centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) and especially the [How do I ask a good question?](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section. The title of your question "What is the difference between 'de' and 'des' in French?" will not be answered here, we only answer questions about one specific problem. Your question could be improved if you want a satisfying answer: – the use of *de* or *des* in all your sentence fragments could depend on context so if you want to know why they are correct you must provide more context;

Comment: – the reasons for choosing *de* or *des*  might be different for each pair of fragments, so it might be better to ask different questions for each pair. You say you are confused, if you can say why it, might help getting a useful answer.

Comment: Ok thanks I will modify the question and provide more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les profils des clients. Cette phrase signifie que cela porte sur le profil de chaque client. Un profil par client. 5 clients = 5 profils.

Les profils de clients. Celle-ci signifie que un profil peut correspondre à plusieurs clients. 5 clients ont 2 profils (ex: Le profil acheteur compulsif et le profil acheteur raisonné).

Raisonnement similaire pour ces phrases:
Les données des comportements des clients. Le comportement de *chaque* client *individuel* est observé.

Les données de comportements des clients. Cette phrase signifie plus un comportement global (moyenne de tous les clients) qui serait observé à travers plusieurs données (temps passé, panier moyen, réceptivité aux offres).